# Creating Directory, Text file and write in that text with TextBox

Tags: c#

I have issue with this code Access denied 
Code is working even when i check the text file i have text but i have Access denied Error

I tried to add App Manifest and have administrator rights even i try to set security on C drive for full access for my account

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string dir = @"C:\Knjigovodstvo\Firme\"+textBox1.Text+"";
        if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
        }

        File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(dir, "Podaci.txt"), textBox1.Text);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(dir);
       sw.WriteLine("" + textBox1.Text + "");
       sw.Close();
   }
```

Just  trying to not having the error because it is working

Comment: Why do you use _textBox1.Text_ for both the directory name and the content to write in the file Podaci.txt?

Comment: Because that is the "Name"  and for directory i will have few of them and want to separate them with name and I also need that "Name" in text file because it is basic Information

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. You use the Text property not the Name property. So you are trying to create a folder with the content of the textbox not with the Name of the textbox

Comment: You never close the stream writer, so once it works it wont again..

Comment: First, you're creating `new StreamWriter(dir)` using `dir` not the full path of file.

Comment: @Steve TextBox is there because i will not know the "Name" of the let's say product  so i will leave it for user  to enter and with that to create folder text file and text inside

Comment: @BugFinder Sorry my  bad didn't place it here in code I will edit it now

Comment: So, you have a textbox where your user types "Product1" and you try to create a folder named "Product1", after that you create a file in that new folder named "Podaci.txt" and its content will be again "Product1" ? If this is the case then you don't need the StreamWriter lines, just the File.WriteAllText and @AlessandroD'Andria has got it right. With those lines you are trying to write into a directoryname not into a file

Comment: @Steve Yes  Podaci.txt  will have more lines but  Yes i am trying to get that

Comment: As explained above by @AlessandroD'Andria you are trying to write to a directory name not to a file

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys found the solution with  @AlessandroD'Andria and @Steve help

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string dir = @"C:\Knjigovodstvo\Firme\"+textBox1.Text+"";
        if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
        }

        File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(dir, "Podaci.txt"), textBox1.Text);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Podaci.txt");
       sw.WriteLine("" + textBox1.Text + "");
       sw.Close();
   }
```

Comment: you know thats writing one copy to the place you wanted, and one to whereever it ran from right?